# Selectively Optimizing a Keras Model with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm creating a GAN (generative adversariel network) using both Tensorflow and Keras. The issue that occurs is when I attempt to pass my list of generator training parameters into the `vars_list` for the training step.

My generator looks like

```
def create_generator(z_noise):
    #build layer one
    l1 = Dense(h1_size)(z_noise)
    L1 = LeakyReLU(0.1)(l1)
    #layer 2 
    l2 = Dense(h2_size)(L1)
    L2 = LeakyReLU(0.1)(l2)
    #layer 3
    l3 = Dense(h3_size)(l2)
    #generated data
    x_generate = sigmoid(l3)
    #params
    g_params = [l1, L1, l2, L2, l3]

    return x_generate, g_params
```

The x_generate is then passed into the discriminator which is still written in Tensorflow and yet to be converted to keras. That portion works correctly up until I pass in the optimization parameters.

```
#generate the nets

x_generated, g_params = create_generator(z_prior)
y_data, y_generated, d_params = create_discriminator(x_data, x_generated, keep_prob)

#declare loss functions
d_loss = - (tf.log(y_data) + tf.log(1 - y_generated)) # inverted due to inability to do normal maximization
g_loss = - tf.log(y_generated)

#optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)
d_trainer = optimizer.minimize(d_loss, var_list=d_params)
g_trainer = optimizer.minimize(g_loss, var_list=g_params)
```

The outcome is an error stating

```
NotImplementedError: ('Trying to update a Tensor ', <tf.Tensor 'dense_4/BiasAdd:0' shape=(256, 20) dtype=float32>)
```

on the line

```
g_trainer = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=g_params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the activations of the layers, rather than the trainable parameters in those layers in `var_list`.

Try something like the following:

```
def create_generator(z_noise):
    with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        #build layer one
        l1 = Dense(h1_size)(z_noise)
        L1 = LeakyReLU(0.1)(l1)
        #layer 2 
        l2 = Dense(h2_size)(L1)
        L2 = LeakyReLU(0.1)(l2)
        #layer 3
        l3 = Dense(h3_size)(l2)
        #generated data
        x_generate = sigmoid(l3)

    g_params = tf.get_collection(
            tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='generator')

    return x_generate, g_params
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Model trains perfectly now